# How to trigger a function (to start processing) ONLY AFTER the form is loaded in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

I have try formloaded, it doesn't work.

```
   private void UserControl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {    
          //This function call with begin the processing.
          EnrolFingerprint();    
    }
```

I want the processing to take place only after the form has been loaded, so that the user can see what is going on. Currently, the processing take place and then only it loads the form.

Comment: Put it in a thread with a sleep. Make sure to invoke so that it executes on the same thread.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use background worker or thread. cause I am using a third party dll in my EnrolFingerPrint(), and it doesn't allow another thread.

Comment: Thats why I said you should invoke the dispatcher.

Comment: As long as EnrolFingerprint runs synchronously in the UI thread, it will inevitably block that thread and hence the UI. You have to find a way to make it asynchronous. Using a Thread with a Dispatcher call or a BackgroundWorker are however outdated approaches. You would actually use [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)